# Sed output into sed input?

Tags: sed, rhel7

I am creating a two Tomcat instance cluster using mod_jk.
The instances need to communicate with each other, so they each need to know the other's private IP address. The addresses need to be added to a `workers.properties` file, and also to the `server.xml` file. I am trying to automate this.

I have created an ec2 userdata script that uses outputs from a stack to write the IP addresses to a text file, which looks like:

```
10.0.75.75
10.0.75.142
```

(The top one is "tomcatnode1ip", the bottom one is "tomcatnode2ip".)

I can run

```
sed '1!d' /home/ec2-user/scripts/properties/host.properties"
```

and it prints line1 of `host.properties`, which is an IP address, I can also output that to another txt file.

What I want to do is overwrite variables in `workers.properties` and `server.xml` with the IP addresses of the 2 servers.

This is done with

```
sed -i 's/tomcatnode1ip/tomcat1/g' /usr/share/tomcat/conf/server.xml
```

and

```
sed -i 's/tomcatnode1ip/tomcat1/g' /etc/httpd-2.4.39/modules/tomcat-connectors-1.2.46-src/conf/workers.properties
```

using the variables `tomcat1` and `tomcat2`.

So basically I have two working sed scripts, and what I want is for either:

- the output of the first script to feed the second script, or
- nest the scripts, so that the IP address is sent directly to the variable

Are either of these possible?

Comment: You seem to have *four* scripts. Are you trying to combine them into *two,* or into *one?*

Comment: Just 2: The first one prints a line from the host.properties file, the second one replaces a variable in a different file (there are two separate files - server.xml and workers.properties - but they use the same variables, although I would need to run the command separately for each one). Thank You!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide concise, testable sample input and expected output so we get a better idea of WHAT it is you're trying to do rather than HOW you're trying to do it so we can bet help you figure out the right way to do whatever it is you're trying to do.